# Conversion string to double is not valid

Tags: vb.net

following code gives error conversion from string to doble is not valid

```
Dim TaxRebate = CDbl(ComboBox1.SelectedItem) * 0.01 * CDbl(Premium)
```

help in to this is appreciated
Sunilsb

Comment: what is the value for the variable `Premium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'Dim TaxRebate = CDbl(ComboBox1.SelectedItem) * 0.01 * CDbl(Premium)

Dim value1 As String
Dim number1 As Double

Dim value2 As String
Dim number2 As Double

Dim TaxRebate As Double

value1 = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
value2 = Premium.ToString()

If False = Double.TryParse(value1, number1) then
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.", value1)
ElseIf False = Double.TryParse(value2, number2) Then
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is outside the range of a Double.", value2)
Else
    TaxRebate = 0.01 * number1 * number2 
End If
```

Comment: If I wanted to declare then  can I use Dim TaxRebate = 0.01 * number1 * number2 after writing above codes

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified style
>   and culture-specific format to its double-precision floating point
>   number equivalent.

And its there since 1.1 version

Comment: I am unable to do that how to do that for above example

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
Dim TaxRebate As Double = CDbl(ComboBox1.SelectedItem) * 0.01 * CDbl(Premium)
```

will sort out problem.

What ever is  variables/textstrings we have to declare them

Dim ------ As Doule =